# .NET Api create Insert POST API for object with Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have a model called Trucks, and a Model called Categories. There is a many to many relationship between the 2 models. I have created a Table called TruckCategory to map the many to many relationship. I am trying to create an API that will insert a new food truck with its categories. How do i do so in such a case?

```
public class Truck
{
    public int TruckId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 5)]
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
    public Address Location { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<TruckCategory> TruckCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, create an Api Controller class
like this one

```
public class PostingApiController : ApiController
{
    public string CreateTruckCategory(TruckAndCategory model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new YourEntity())
            {
                //extract the truck model           
                Truck truck = new Truck
                {
                    //assign variables example
                    Title = model.Truck.Title;
                };
                //save truck data to db
                db.Truck.Add(truck);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //keep track of the truck id if it is auto increment
                var truckId = truck.TruckId;

                //also in the same way extract and save the category model keeping track of the ID,
                var categoryId = category.Id;

                //the save the link table with both IDs
                TruckCategory truckCategory = new TruckCategory
                {
                    CategoryId = categoryId;
                    TruckId = truckId;
                };
                //then save this link table
                db.TruckCategory.Add(truckCategory);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "failure";
        }
    }
}
```

where you have your model as

```
public class TruckAndCategory{
    //class declaration here
    public Truck truck {get; set;}
    public Category category {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bosco! What im confused with is that when I get say a POST Request, how do i parse the data for the categories

Comment: You can use javascript to do that by collecting all the form variables, maybe you show me how the form looks so that I can write the jquery ajax post for you but the syntax for jquery ajax post is $.post(URL,data,callback);